# Microsoft Graph API - Follow Site

Tags: api, sharepoint, graph

I'm trying to make users follow a SharePoint Online site using the Microsoft Graph API. When I enter my user ID in the below scenario, the operation is successful. When I use another user's ID, the operation fails with a 403 error. The text says to check the permissions in the modify box but all permissions are granted. Is this just a limitation of the API that you can't make another user follow a site?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Riw68.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My test result is same with you, I think follow site should be a personal action, so setting follow site for others is prohibited.